# writing a search query for search result web part

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, web-part, search, search-results

Is it possible to write a search query that will find sites/subsite that the current user has been shared?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

contentclass:”STS_Site” contentclass:”STS_Web”

This search query will return you all the site collections and subsites that the user has access to.